# Can I use User Controls in MVC 4 aspx View Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I have a mature open source User controls used in my project for control panel  for navigation. However, I am now on a new project using MVC 4. I noticed there is also aspx view engine provided, can I still use the custom control in the new project?

As one of my concerns, the control functions a url redirect but also do some postback stuff such as setting session values. I am wondering if postback is a main issue that blocks me using it?

[icons http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8209/captureyhf.png](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8209/captureyhf.png)

Answer (score 1):

The bigger question is, do you really want to try? If you're moving to MVC, why not embrace the new architecture and take this as an opportunity to get your old code up-to-date. You're always going to reach a breaking point when it becomes better to rewrite old stuff than to try to keep adapting it to new tech, and a move from forms apps to MVC seems like a really good time to make that switch (especially when it comes to using the Session State).

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  Chances are, most controls won't work.  This is because they depend on ViewState to function.  Controls that do not depend on ViewState will work.  So, if you can disable ViewState and still use the control, chance are it will will, unless it has some other dependency on specific WebForms functionality that isn't present in MVC.

This is not, however, a recommended practice, as this support is sort of accidental and not really supported by the MVC team.. thus it could disappear in a later version.  Also, it creates a sort of split-brain design that is just poor practice.